# How to save sql script in oracle when there have special characters, like japanese characher 'あいうえおのう' and '\r\n'

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, oracle-sqldeveloper, encode

I am writing a sql procedure in oracle to replace special characters into the correct ones, like `&#x30cd;` to 'ネ', and '' to '/r/n'.
How can I deal with the encode problem as when I save the procedure to sql file, some code seems to be gibberish, like `?`

PS: I mean in sql develover, I right click the procedure --> 'export' --> save as signal file, here which encoding should i choose? UTF-8 or UTF-32 will cause the gibberish problem.[image]

Comment: Why do you have `&#x30cd;` at first place? The best idea would be to not send that to a database.

Comment: I am writing the sql to solve the  `&#x30cd;` problem. I have found the right character to replace `&#x...`, the problem is that when I save the sql file, the characters change to be `?`

Comment: is your field nvarchar?

Comment: varchar2.  I mean saving the process to a sql file, then the characters change to `?`

Comment: So why do you send the `&#x30cd;` to database?

Comment: `&#x30cd;` is the bad data in database,  I need to replace it to the right character. The problem  is when exporting the procedure to sql file in sql developer, I don't know which encoding to choose , and the  right character is to be `?` when exporting out in a wrong encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find another way to solve this situation. I create a table to store `&#x30cd;` and correct value, then exp the table as dmp file. We can deal with the data from the table just need to import the dmp file first.